# Permissions required on FILE and FOLDER in order to write to file?

Tags: php, file, unix, permissions, file-permissions

If I want to append to a log file as follows:

```
file_put_contents("ip.txt", $ip, FILE_APPEND);
```

what must the file's permissions be (UNIX)? Do the directory permissions also have to be changed, or does an adjustment to the file's permissions suffice?

Comment: what do you mean by this? the octal values needed?

Comment: i would start by saying `file_put_contents` dose not 'append'; it will replace if ip.txt already exists

Comment: Use either 644 or 777 for files. 644 is better and should suffice. 755 for folders is usually best. Rarely would you want to use anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The most common permission for files are 644, which gives the owner permission to read and write, and read to the group and others.

In order to write files in a directory you need to give it execute access, so 7xx would be the one you need. As for permissions to the group and others, it depends on the situation.

The most common permissions for directories are 755; which means (besides what's said above) that the group and others have read and execution permission. 
Execution permission on a directory means that you can enter, which you need to write a file in it.

EDIT:

```
Why would the Group and World fields not be set, if this will be executed from a
website? Why not 666 instead of 644? (I might be misunderstanding what Group and 
World mean.)
```

Group and Others should be interpreted in the context of the system where the file is located, as in Unix groups. Others are those users in the system that are not withing the group and are not the owner.

All this however plays almost no role in the context of a Web application because it is always the Web server (ie. Apache) the one who runs the scripts that manipulate the files. So the only really relevant permission at this point is the firs of the three.

If you had access to your server via a console and you attempted to access that `ip.txt` file; then you'd have to be logged in as a user with enough permissions to access the file. That is where the second and third digits come into play.

So lets say your file's permissions are set as 666: then any user that logs in would be able to read and write that file (provided they also have execute permission on the directory containing the file). If the file has permissions 644 then only the owner would have permissions to write, while group users and others would only have read access.

But again, within the context of a Web application, the only permission you really care about is the first one.

Comment: Why would the Group and World fields not be set, if this will be executed from a website? Why not 666 instead of 644? (I might be misunderstanding what Group and World mean.)